# Securely encrypting credit card data

Tags: encryption, credit-card

I came to a situation where I am required to store credit card holder data in my database and I'm looking for the most secure way of dealing with this. Note that I am fully aware of PCI-DSS so my question is purely about the encryption aspect.

Now I have decided to use Curve25519 public key encryption (using libsodium) and the private key is stored securely, offline. Let's assume I implemented this correctly. I figured that when I only encrypt the credit card number and the expiry date this would be easy to brute force as the first 6 and last 4 digits of the card number are known as well as the expiry date, because they are already plain text in the database somewhere.

Let's say I'm encrypting this

```
1234561111118762|10|21|VISA
```

Now the only secret in this string is `111111` (6 digits). It would cost someone 10^6 tries to find out this number.

But what if I am encrypting like this

```
1234561111118762|10|21|VISA|aVeryLongPsuedoRandomStringGeneratedUniquelyForEachEncryptedString
```

Would this prevent a brute force 10^6 scenario? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The fact that you need to ask this should be enough of a red flag in your own mind...

Comment: I'm just saying.  Either you're willfully ignoring your obligations under PCI compliance or you're not qualified to implement them.

Comment: My question here is about encryption. Let's not move away from that subject. If you have nothing to add besides making assumptions about my PCI compliancy you're wasting your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking *just about encryption...*

I'm assuming by "brute-force" you mean take the public key, encrypt and compare to the ciphertext you have stored.  If this is what you mean, then the answer depends on the implementation.

You need to determine if the implementation is deterministic - if it is, then yes, it will be possible to brute-force and compare.  If it is not (which you would expect), then this won't be a problem.

I expect libsodium has this problem covered.

Comment: That was very helpful :) So I can safely assume that as long as (correctly implemented) probabilistic encryption is used there is no way of brute forcing and comparing to the stored text.